# is there any css rule that allows to select all containters including a certain string?

Tags: css

I would like to know whether is there a way in css to apply a rule to all containers including a certain string.
For example:
I have: class="hello-english", class="goodbye-english" and class="tomorrow-english"
Is there a way to select all classes containing the string "english" in the class name?
Thanks

Comment: Technically yes i suspect something like:  `div[class*="english"] { .... }` could work; but it's a pretty sloppy selector.

Comment: Do you want all the classes which have 'english' anywhere in their name whih is what your text suggests or do you want just those classes which end in '-english' which is what your example suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

That's basically, (or at least one answer to it)

```css
element[class$="-english"] {
  ...insert rules here
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks